# android RecyclerView notifyDataSetChange method causes all items change on click on specific item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a RecyclerView in my project that shows a list of ticket messages.
I use pagination to show the messages in parts. I think notifyDataSetChange is the method I should use to add newly added items.

Below is the code for how I handle adding new items to my list:

```
public void makeList(List<SingleTicketModel> ticketMessages) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ticketMessages.size(); i++) {
        ticket.add(
                new TicketItemModel(
                        ticketMessages.get(i).getContent(),
                        ticketMessages.get(i).getCreatedAt(),
                        ticketMessages.get(i).getDirection(),
                        ticketMessages.get(i).getAgentName(),
                        ticketMessages.get(i).getAttachment()
                )

        );
    }
    if (ticketAdaptor == null) {
        ticketAdaptor = new TicketAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), ticket, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ticketAdaptor);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                loadMoreProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getTickets(loginToken, current_page,ticketID);
            }
        });
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    } else {

        ticketAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

There may be an attachment in some messages and here is my problem:

When a user clicks on attachment button, the button is being converted to a progressBar as long as the attachment is downloaded.

But If the user clicks on attachment icon, all attachment icons in the list turn into progressBar and this means that setOnClickListener method executes on all items!

The important thing is that this happens only if notifyDataSetChange method is called.

I conclude that if the number of messages is low and there is no need to load more information, this will not happen.

In addition, another point that I think is related to this problem:

If the user clicks the attachment button (in which case the imageButton image changes after the download is complete), It seems that the item will be rebuilt by scrolling the list and the attachment button image will return to the first state.(again after new data is being added to the list)

here is my adaptor file :

```
public class TicketAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TicketAdaptor.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private List<TicketItemModel> ticket;
View view;

public TicketAdaptor(Context context, List<TicketItemModel> ticket, Activity activity){

    this.context = context;
    this.ticket = ticket;
    this.activity = activity;

}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



        this.view = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.ticket_item_in, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.ticketDescription.setText(ticket.get(position).getContent());
    holder.ticketDate.setText(ticket.get(position).getCreatedAt());
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){

        case 1 :
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radius_background_gray);
            holder.ticketDate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radius_background_light_gray);
            holder.ticketStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_attachment_black_24dp);
            break;
        case 11 :
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radius_background_gray);
            holder.ticketDate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radius_background_light_gray);
            break;
        case 3 :
            holder.ticketStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_attachment_black_24dp);
            break;
        default: break;

    }
    holder.ticketTitle.setText(ticket.get(position).getAgentName() + " said :");

    holder.ticketStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean counter = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (requestPermission() == true) {
                File attachmentFile = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/"
                        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + "/"
                        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.ticket_directory)
                        + "/"
                        + ticket.get(position).getCreatedAt().replaceAll("\\s|:|-","") + ".jpeg" ));

                if( !counter && !attachmentFile.exists())
                {
                    holder.attachmentProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ticketStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    downloadAttachment(ticket.get(position)
                                    .getAttachment(),
                            ticket
                                    .get(position)
                                    .getCreatedAt()
                                    .replaceAll("\\s|:|-","") + ".jpeg",
                            holder.ticketStatus,holder.attachmentProgressBar);
                         counter = true;
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    File file = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/"
                            + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                            + "/"
                            + context.getResources().getString(R.string.ticket_directory)),
                             ticket.get(position).getCreatedAt().replaceAll("\\s|:|-","")
                            + ".jpeg"
                    );
                    intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            file),"image/*");
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }


        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    String Direction = ticket.get(position).getDirection();
    String Attachment = ticket.get(position).getAttachment();
    if(Direction.equals("out")){
        if (Attachment != null)
            return 1;
        else return 11;
    }else if(!(Direction.equals("out"))){
        if(Attachment != null)
            return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ticket.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView ticketTitle;
    TextView ticketDescription;
    TextView ticketDate;
    ImageView ticketStatus;
    ProgressBar attachmentProgressBar;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.ticketTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_agent);
        this.ticketDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_description);
        this.ticketDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_date);
        this.ticketStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_attachment);
        this.attachmentProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attachment_progressbar);
        attachmentProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

private void downloadAttachment(String url, final String imageName, final View attachmentIcon, final View attachmentProgressBar){

    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.getAttachment(url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            saveAttachment saveAttachment = new saveAttachment(imageName,attachmentIcon, attachmentProgressBar);
            saveAttachment.execute(response.body().byteStream());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}

private class saveAttachment extends AsyncTask<InputStream,Void,Boolean>{

    private  String imageName;
    private View attachmentIcon;
    private View attachmentProgressBar;

    public saveAttachment(String imageName, View attachmentIcon, View attachmentProgressBar) {
        super();
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.attachmentIcon = attachmentIcon;
        this.attachmentProgressBar = attachmentProgressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(InputStream... inputStreams) {
        InputStream inputStream = inputStreams[0];
        final File directory = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/"
                + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                + "/"
                + context.getResources().getString(R.string.ticket_directory)
        ));
        if (!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdirs();
        final File myImageFile = new File(directory, imageName);
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myImageFile);
            byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        attachmentProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((ImageView) attachmentIcon).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_slow_motion_video_black_24dp);
        attachmentIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}

}
```

(I removed some of the code that did not relate to the topic.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this could be a problem from mismatched positions, since you are adding more to the list. I would suggest setting your OnClickListener on the ViewHolder constructor. The position parameter on the onBindViewHolder method should not be treated as static (when used in anonymous classes like your listener). See if things get better.

Also, you could use notifyItemChanged to just change the one clicked like:

```
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
```

inside your click listener callback.

So, your code would get more like this:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.ticketTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_agent);
    this.ticketDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_description);
    this.ticketDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_date);
    this.ticketStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_attachment);
    this.attachmentProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attachment_progressbar);
    attachmentProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ticketStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    boolean counter = false;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (requestPermission() == true) {
            File attachmentFile = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/"
                    + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                    + "/"
                    + context.getResources().getString(R.string.ticket_directory)
                    + "/"
                    + ticket.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCreatedAt().replaceAll("\\s|:|-","") + ".jpeg" ));

            if (!counter && !attachmentFile.exists()) {
                attachmentProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ticketStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downloadAttachment(ticket.get(getAdapterPosition()).getAttachment(),
                        ticket.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCreatedAt().replaceAll("\\s|:|-","") + ".jpeg",
                        ticketStatus, attachmentProgressBar);
                counter = true;
                // Update UI only for this item.
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                File file = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/"
                        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                        + "/"
                        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.ticket_directory)),
                        ticket.get(getAdapterPosition()).getCreatedAt().replaceAll("\\s|:|-","")
                                + ".jpeg"
                );
                intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        file),"image/*");
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: I did not understand you. Could you show your solution in my code?

Comment: Again, I emphasize that all these problems are specific to the time when new data is added to the list

Comment: I am outdoors right now, I ll give you an update in a few hours.

Comment: Oh ok. I am sorry I wasn't of much help. You can also check if 
 your EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener is causing any problem by removing it and try to reproduce the problem